# PHP, How to push elements into this array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

Example array:

```
$r["NO"] = array(
"hello" => "hey",
"hey" => array("oij", "ioj"),
"hola" => "hia"
);
```

How can I add

```
"blabla" => "hey"
```

Now in the bottom of that array?

End result should be:

```
$r["NO"] = array(
"hello" => "hey",
"hey" => array("oij", "ioj"),
"hola" => "hia",
"blabla" => "hey"
);
```

i tried various array_push without any luck.

Comment: `"hey"` already maps to `array("oij", "ioj"),`.

Comment: I think you could not do this since "hey" will be a duplicated key. B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys within an associative array.

Update:: You can just set the key => value like so:

```
$r["NO"]["blabla"] = "hey";
```

Comment: that was not intentional, changed it now.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth No harm, no foul, no need to feel stupid! Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, the key must be unique. You could image the php's associative array as the hash map in other language.

***Edit:***

For your edited case, you could just do `$r["NO"]['blabla'] = 'value';`

Comment: it was not intentional so changed it now.